# KeyCloak custom registration url

Tags: reactjs, security, frontend, keycloak, freemarker

My Requirement is to append a custom request parameter in registration url of keylcloak and extract it into form

My Attempt:
Using keycloack.js adapter ,I am able to create a custom registration  url as below in my React project

```
      const baseRegisterUrl = _kc.createRegisterUrl();
      const url = new URL(baseRegisterUrl);
      url.searchParams.set('custom_param', 'custom_value')
```

Now I am using customised login theme which means to add changes to a registration ftl file .I want to extract this custom_param in my custom keycloak form , is it possible as I have tried to include a script but ftl does not allow direct intervention of JavaScript ,like

```
  var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  console.log("Current URL: " + currentUrl);
<#assign queryString= currentUrl>
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to extend FormAction class of keycloack and override buildpage method which renders the form using Java SPI.Then put the created jar in provider folder of keycloack so that our custom spi gets loaded and can be used in keycloack